# Nested React Components with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

To nest components in react using the regular JSX I've seen the following snippet:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Options:</span>
      <Copmonent.Comment.List />
      <Copmonent.Comment.Form />
    </div>
  );
```

What's the equivalent using the `React.DOM` (and coffeescript)?

```
render: ->
  React.DOM.div {},
    React.DOM.span {}, "Options:"
    ???
    ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create factories from components:

```
List = React.createFactory(ListClass)
Form = React.createFactory(FormClass)
```

Then, we can call them directly wherever we want:

```
render: ->
  React.DOM.div {},
    React.DOM.span {}, "Options:"
    Component.Comment.List {}
    Component.Comment.Form {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-react to transfrom.

With this lib render looks similar to plain .JSX

```
render: () ->
  <div className="some-class">
    <SomeComponent />
  </div>
```